# Possible bug in Stack Overflow Android application

Tags: discussion, bug, android-app

I notice that the results are not the same in Stack Overflow Android app and the official site in google chrome or another browser :

[image: differente results]

Note that android application always gives great results than the other one.

Any explanation, please?

Comment: It also seems to think there are *fewer answers* in a given tag. Cached data stuck somewhere?

Comment: There are no bugs in the SO android app. The app itself is a bug.

Comment: The app includes questions too it appears, which is wrong. Only *non-cw answers* count towards the tag badges.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe they are not using the same business logic, same queries to count the score of the official web site

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't.

Comment: either the answers marked as wiki answer

Comment: @GhostCat I agree, I hat this politic story, I will not participate in this at all ;)